# DataStore/Datapusher error determining header type

Tags: ckan

I am trying to upload a CSV file to a CKAN DataStore and one of its columns was determined as type Numeric even though one of the values in that column was alphanumeric. The result is an error when Datapusher tries to load this very record.

Is there a way I can correct the Datastore type for a particular column in the file?

Versions:

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

CKAN version 2.6.0 (installed from package)

Postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer:

The datapusher is guessing datatypes based on data at the beginning of the file, later this turns out to be a bad guess and a string cannot be turned into a number. The latest CKAN (try it on beta.ckan.org) has a workaround for this: try the upload/datapush once, then after it is finished (with failure), use the data dictionary (e.g. https://beta.ckan.org/dataset/{dataset name here}/dictionary/{resource id here} to override the data type of the column, then go to the datastore and do the push again.

Original answer:

Does it manage to load the file but just not that record, or does it give up? If you upgrade to 2.7 and use the latest Datapusher code, I think you can use the Data Dictionary feature to set the type manually, manually start the push to datastore again, and it will use the type you have set instead of the guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The file is loaded, but not completely. An error message is logged ('CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 500 Internal Server Error') and the loading stops at that record.

Comment: OK, but can you tell if any records are in the datastore? It sounds like they aren't. Is it an option to clean that record out, do the upload, set the data dictionary and then replace with the original file? Seems a bit circuitous I know...

Comment: Yes, there are records in the datastore. The dataset can be seen at https://demo.ckan.org/dataset/teste-cias-abertas/resource/1d7e45e5-b159-46a2-bdce-90393c7a8a2b. The .csv file has 2,190 records but only 1,750 are displayed in the Data Explorer. The value that crashes the upload is at row 1,761, column 'DDD_TEL_RESP'

Comment: Hi, I tested the file on demo.ckan.org and see that it didn't have the feature I'm talking about. On beta.ckan.org it works:
https://beta.ckan.org/dataset/test-stack-overflow/dictionary/2b05b6a7-e282-402c-917f-5b5e940e92d3

(actually, that page shouldn't really be visible in edit mode, I expect you get an authorization failure if you try to save, but you can try the whole upload etc. yourself on beta.ckan.org)

But I cannot see from looking at the file which column it is that has the transition from numeric to text?

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance. I can see that this 'Data Dictionary' feature, in a later version of CKAN, might help. By the way, the column which has the transition from numeric to text is column #39 (header 'DDD_TEL_RESP')

Comment: I did as suggested and the preview is now showing all the records: https://beta.ckan.org/dataset/teste-cias-abertas/resource/27da7323-3b45-4ffa-a98f-ac97ecec4a91. Thank you!

Comment: No probs, perhaps you can accept/upvote the answer - I edited it to give the final insturctions